# how do I check if an a href contains aria-current. And if true execute code to parent and siblings. using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, attributes, jquery-selectors

I have an a tag.

```
<a href="#" aria-current="page">Disarray Body</a>
```

When the link is open. the browser adds ==>aria-current="page". How can I select that element with the atribute of aria-current="page" And execute code to its parent and sibling?

I've tried this.

```
var items = $('.menu-item>a');

if (items.hasattr("aria-current", "page") === true) {
        items.parent.css( "background-color", "red" )};
```

But it declears as undefined. how do I let jquery find out witch link is currently open in the brouwser. A.K.A. =>aria-current="page"?

Below you can find part of the html.

```
    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">portriats</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-473" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
                    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">Disarray Body</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-617" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
                <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">#Girls</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">Item2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
                    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">object1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-619" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
                <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">Object2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Attribute Equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('a[aria-current="page"]');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5my1dL7b/)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to style the current page differently. Since the current page already has `aria-current="page"` (as it should), you can styling in CSS like follows, you can use the attribute selector:

```css
[aria-curent="page"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```